# Иероглифы в запросе

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, bottle

Отправляю запрос с кириллицей, а сервер на питоне получает другой текст:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И можно ли как-нибудь сразу отправить текст с кириллицей или преобразовать это в кириллицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно, браузер таким образом кодирует символы.

Перекодирующая кодировка описана в стандарте [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) и называется *URL-encoding*, *URLencoded* или *percent‐encoding*.

Вы можете преобразовать `URL` обратно, используя модуль `urllib.parse`.

***Пример:***

```py
import urllib.parse


def main():
    url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F'
    print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```html
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Википедия
```