# Название файла не пишется на русском языке PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо, чтобы файл excel в письме outlook был с русским названием (кириллицей), ниже кусок кода, для теста, после действия att.add_header русский текст получает другую кодировку.

```
filename = 'тест'
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
print(att)
msg.attach(att)
```

результат:

```
Content-Type: application/xlsx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Comment: Может так:`filename = 'тест'.ecnode('koi8-r')` ?

Comment: Не сработало(  
Вот такая ошибка: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Тогда надо `decode`

Comment: Это называется _URL-encoding_. Посмотрите [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044476/339283), возможно, он поможет Вам.

Comment: Как отдельную переменную перекодировать получилось, но конкретно в методе add_header, все равно не дает сделать декод.

Почитал в документации про метод, там можно поставить наименование кодировки, и все равно на выходе получается пустое значение, пробовал cp866 и koi8-r
https://kite.com/python/docs/email.message.Message.add_header - ссылка
И в outlook я получаю фаил: @вложение без имени.dat@

Comment: Есть идеи или решение?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло прописать filename вручную с кодировкой KOI8-R

```
from email.header import Header

att.add_header(
  "Content-Disposition",
  'attachment; filename=' + Header(filename, 'KOI8-R').encode()
)
```

Comment: да вы просто неофит какой-то. надо было тёплую ламповую [ebcdic-880](https://en.everybodywiki.com/EBCDIC_880) пользовать.